# How many users on christianity.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, feature-request, users

Is it possible to know the number of total users of christianity.stackexchange.com?

I went around the site but couldn't see it.

In case there isn't: which are the reasons of this choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the sidebar [here](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/139/week/christianity), you'll see a list of reputation levels and the number of users at or above each level. At the moment, there are 1,451 users with at least 1 reputation (which is basically everyone).

Comment: Also on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11655/christianity): "240
avid users
1,607
total users"

Answer (score 5):

The [Users page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users) is a 9 x 4 grid of users and there are currently 40 pages since the last page isn't necessarily full, I'd put the site at somewhere between 1440 and 1480 users.

Not sure why I bothered to answer this since [El'endia](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1158/4) says the same thing, but what the hey, it's 5:00 and I'm going home.